# Can't update npm - code EN0ENT -2

Tags: node.js, npm

I just used Homebrew to install Node. It seemed alright but when I try to update npm with

```
npm install -g npm
```

I get the following error:

```
ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/myusername/-g
ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "npm"
ERR! node v0.12.7
ERR! npm v2.14.2
ERR! path /Users/myusername/-g
ERR! code EN0ENT
ERR! errno -2

ERR! enoent EN0NT, open '/Users/myusername/-g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in the past with a similar issue:

```
npm cache clean
```

You can also try running it as `sudo`

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

Comment: This seemed to work one time, and then I get the same error again with the next package:

    sudo npm install -g ios-sim@3.1.1